# How to access to the result content of javascript request in c# code

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm trying to parse the results of each runner of [Paris marathon](http://www.schneiderelectricparismarathon.com/en/event/results/results-marathon)
web page.

But, the body of the page is an ajax request.

So, I tried to load the page in a WeBrowser winform component. Even if the the visual render is OK I still cannot find the corresponding HTML result of each runner in the InnerHTM/OutterHTML property of the WebBrowser component.

How could I do :/ Thanks for your help!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new MyScript();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.schneiderelectricparismarathon.com/fr/l-evenement/resultats/resultats-marathon");
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript: window.external.CallServerSideCode();");
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class MyScript
    {
        public void CallServerSideCode()
        {
            var doc = ((Form1)Application.OpenForms[0]).webBrowser1.Document;
            // I cannot find the ranking of each runner in here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read your post and realize that it makes no sense.

Comment: tell me why it makes no sense instead of juging with no arg. Did you understand my prob ? I'm just trying to understand ....

Comment: There is no real context provided and no code examples here. Just a vaig description of something you are doing followed by please help. So your question.

It's like if i ask a similar question about what I am working on now. e.g. "I have the dates for billed time in the graphs flags and now i need to include the date in the text. I populate the graphs in the ajax response and all the data pulls through. Now i need to know how to include the date in the flag. please help." - Do you have any idea what I am talking about here? That's how i feel about your question.

Comment: Oh ok I understand now :) Sorry, I will be more specific next time! Thanks for your advice @Harry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See that result is returned in this url

> http://www.aso.fr/massevents/resultats/ajax.php?course=mar17&langue=us&version=3&action=search

using an html parser ([HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex))

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var html = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.aso.fr/massevents/resultats/ajax.php?v=1493287097&course=mar17&langue=us&version=3&action=search");
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    var details = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='footable']")
                    .Descendants("tr")
                    .Select(tr => tr.Descendants("td").Select(x => x.InnerText).Take(5).ToList())
                    .Where(x=>x.Count==5)
                    .ToList();
}
```

the printable form of this result is (which is List of List):

```
1   02:06:10    7   LONYANGATA  Paul
2   02:06:57    1   CHEBOGUT    Stephen
3   02:07:12    9   YEGO    Solomon
4   02:07:19    11  ATNAFU  Yitayal
5   02:07:40    4   AYELE   Abayneh
6   02:08:25    8   KIPSANG Asbel
7   02:08:37    5   KOSGEI  Samuel
8   02:08:44    14  MENGICH Richard
9   02:09:46    91  NKHABUTLANE Motlokoa Clement
10  02:10:02    6   KOGO    Micah
11  02:10:11    34  AKOPESHA    Abraham
12  02:10:20    19  CHAHDI  Hassan
13  02:10:30    13  MUTAI   Kipkemei
14  02:10:44    2   KIPTOO  Mark
15  02:13:06    16  MALATY  Benjamin
16  02:14:07    18  DURAND  Yohan
17  02:14:57    24  CHANI   Hassan
18  02:17:55    20  LALIRE  Paul
19  02:17:55    102 TEFERI  Maru
20  02:18:19    101 MORIHASHI   Kansuke
21  02:19:01    99  GUNJI   Takahiro
22  02:20:11    96  NAVARRO Nicolas
23  02:20:47    140 RANCON  Julien
24  02:20:55    205 RIONORIPO   Purity
25  02:20:59    204 BARSOSIO    Agnes
26  02:21:22    202 CHEYECH Flomena
27  02:21:23    39  MASCIOTRA   Julien
28  02:21:36    201 JEPKESHO    Visiline
29  02:22:30    108 ROMERO  Hugo
30  02:22:51    203 MELESE  Yebrgual
31  02:24:23    3066    RAPHAEL Magalhaes Moura
32  02:26:41    105 GUALDI  Giovanni
33  02:27:14    111 NEUSCHWANDER    Florian
34  02:27:31    90  INI Thierry
35  02:27:52    104 CHAILLOU    Thomas
36  02:27:55    5345    HOLLAND Adam
37  02:28:06    991 JEAN    Richard
38  02:28:19    6041    JAEN ORTIZ  Henrry
39  02:28:36    139 COUZON  Clement
40  02:29:07    582 MILANI  Massimiliano Andrea
41  02:29:12    3008    RYCKELYNCK  Benjamin
42  02:29:13    211 GUDETA  Netsanet
43  02:29:21    1104    PURNELLE    Alexandre
44  02:30:24    209 KOWALSKA    Kataryna
45  02:30:24    857 LUCAS   Yoann
46  02:30:32    3967    NEWTON  Mark
47  02:30:35    93  BENICHOU    Thomas
48  02:30:53    753 TASSAROTTI  Luca
49  02:31:01    861 POBLETE Jesus Antonio
50  02:31:25    85  ANFALT  Erik
```

Comment: That's what I needed! How did you find the ajax Url ? And last question, how do you manage the pagination ? Thanks a lot

Comment: @GeJN 1) Press F12 in a browser and open the developer mode. 2) I don't. I just wrote it after your question (See url "http://www.aso.fr/massevents/resultats/ajax.php?course=mar17&langue=us&version=3&action=search&limiter[numpage]=4")